# Why are dreams sometimes remembered and sometimes forgotten?

Tags: memory, dreaming

Why is it that sometimes, when we wake up, we are able to remember what we were just dreaming, but sometimes we don't remember any of it?

Comment: This kind of question are usually accepted on this site but I always think that the OPs would make a better fit and get better answers if they'd ask on [CognitiveScience.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Remi.b true, i always get confused about partner sites. U r free to migrate it to CognitiveScience if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Scientists say that people can have multiple dreams every night and the ones that are not very significant are easily forgotten. Only those experiences that elicit an emotional response (happy, frightened) seem to stick in memory. Suggestions have also been made that being anxious or depressed makes our dreams stick to memory too ([reference](http://www.everydayhealth.com/news/why-you-remember-or-forget-your-dreams/)). A study suggests that people woken up during [REM sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_eye_movement_sleep) seem to recall their dreams more often ([reference](http://www.wisegeek.org/why-do-i-sometimes-remember-my-dreams-vividly-and-other-times-not-at-all.htm)). Here is [a link](http://www.asdreams.org/subidxeduq_and_a.htm) to some common questions about dreams.